# Manually trigger Bootstrap tooltip for checkbox elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am building a "custom" validation module(s) for my web application. I am attaching a change listener to all my checkbox elements. When the change event happens, I check to see if the input is required - if the element is not checked, the element fails validation. This is working perfectly when I manually click any given checkbox. The tooltip shows/destroy as planned.

I am attempting to get the same functionality when the submit button is clicked. The system is seeing that a tooltip (should) get rendered - but it isn't. It's like I need to trigger a click event, but if I do that on a checkbox element - the element will become selected. Not exactly the functionality any user wants. Im not sure how I can pass in a click, without actually clicking anything.

Here is how I am calling my toolip if any given element is invalid:

**Validation.js**

```
Tooltip.initialize($element, {'trigger': 'click', 'placement': 'bottom', 'title': Messages[$element.attr('name') + 'Required']});
```

Here is the code to init & show any given tooltip:

**Tooltip.js**

```
initialize: function($element, options) {
        (Tooltip.debug) ? console.log('-- initialize --') : null;
        (Tooltip.debug) ? console.log('tooltip for: ' + $element.attr('name')) : null;

        var that = this;

        $('#' + $element.attr('name')).tooltip({
            'placement': options.placement,
            'title': options.title,
            'trigger': options.trigger
        }).on({
            'blur': function() {
                switch ($element.attr('type'))
                {
                    case 'checkbox':

                        break;
                    case 'email':
                        that.show($element);
                        break;
                    case 'password':
                        that.show($element);
                        break;
                    case'tel':
                        that.show($element);
                        break;
                    case 'text':
                        that.show($element);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            },
            'focus': function() {
                that.destroy($element);
            }
        });

....

show: function($element) {
        $('#' + $element.attr('id')).tooltip('show');
    },
destroy: function($element) {
        $('#' + $element.attr('id')).tooltip('destroy');
    }

....
```

Comment: Any javascript errors showing? Does $('#id').tooltip('show'); work? Why is case 'checkbox': empty? It would also be great if you could set up a simplified jsfiddle so we can see what is going wrong.

Comment: No errors are showing in the console. Checkbox is empty because that's where I'm currently hung up. :)
[Here is a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/M3Kvr/) Everything is split out into different modules so I've attempted to put everything into a single file. Please forgive what seems like a heck of a lot of JS.

Comment: I had a look but that is too much code for me to sift through. My suggestion is to save yourself a lot of time and hassle and use something like this: http://bootstrapvalidator.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you are trying to achieve since you are not including any sample in fiddle. but maybe instead of using `click()` event, you can use `mouseover()`.
http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: [Here is a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/M3Kvr/) Everything is split out into different modules so I've attempted to put everything into a single file. Please forgive what seems like a heck of a lot of JS.